# Problem in finding relation between annihilating and characteristics polynomial.

Tags: linear-algebra

I have just started studying characteristics polynomial,annihilating polynomial etc.I found that minimal polynomial of a $n \times n$ matrix $A$ is not only the annihilating polynomial of $A$ of least degree but it also divides all the annihilating polynomials of $A$.Now let me ask a question :

Do all the annihilating polynomials of degree $\leq n$ divide the charactertistics polynomial?

It is clear that any annihilating polynomial contains all the distinct factors of the characteristics polynomial.So if the answer to my question is affirmative one then in order to solve this it is sufficient to show that the multiplicities of the factors of the annihilating polynomial of degree $\leq n$ cannot exceed the multiplicities of these factors in the characteristics polynomial.But how can I show this?Please help me.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Well, trivially no. For example, the polynomial $\;(x-1)(x-2)\;$ annihilates the $\;2\times2\;$ identity matrix, yet it doesn't divide that matrix's characteristic polynomial, which is $\;(x-1)^2\;$ ...

Comment: So, @DonAntonio it cannot be said that any $n-th$ degree polynomial which annihilates a $n \times n$ matrix $A$ is the characteristics polynomial of $A$.Am I right?

Comment: @Ar Yes, you are right. What you can say is that it is *a polynomial multiple of the matrix's minimal polynomal*, though.

Comment: Ok.Thanks Don.It helps me a lot.

Comment: Sorry for disturbing you again.I forgot to ask you another question which is :

If all the roots of a polynomial equation $g(t) = 0$ be characteristics roots of a $n \times n$ matrix $A$ then can we say that $g(t)$ is an annihilating polynomial of $A$?
This would enable to fulfill my requirement.

Comment: If *all* the roots of $\;g(t)\;$  are the eigenvalues of $\;A\;$ then $\;g\;$ is a polynomial multiple of the minimal pol. of $\;A\;$ and thus yes: it annihilates $\;A\;$ .

Comment: But how can I show this?

Comment: These are very well known theorems in linear algebra...

Comment: But $g(t)$ may not contain all the factors which are in the expression of minimal polynomial.Then how can the minimal polynomial divide $g(t)$?